# z3 LastIndexOf returns wrong result?

Tags: z3, z3py, lastindexof

z3py's [`LastIndexOf`](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#aa4bf1a97f6d3fd3a1e21c19ec2561279) is supposed to return the *"last index of substring within a string"*. However, it seems to return the wrong results when the substring is located at the end of the string, for example:

```py
>>> import z3
>>> def check_lastindexof(s, sub_list):
...     for c in sub_list:
...         z_index = z3.simplify(z3.LastIndexOf(s, c))
...         v_index = s.rindex(c)
...         try:
...             assert z_index == v_index
...         except Exception as e:
...             print(f'{c: <6} FAILED expected: {v_index: >2}, got: {z_index}')
...
>>>
>>> s = 'abcdefabcdef'
>>> tests = ['a', 'abc', 'f', 'ef', 'abcdef']
>>> check_lastindexof(s, tests)
f      FAILED expected: 11, got: 5
ef     FAILED expected: 10, got: 4
abcdef FAILED expected:  6, got: 0
```

Notably, `LastIndexOf` returns -1 if the substring exists only once in the string, which is clearly wrong as far as I know:

```py
>>> s = 'abcdef'
>>> check_lastindexof(s, tests)
f      FAILED expected:  5, got: -1
ef     FAILED expected:  4, got: -1
abcdef FAILED expected:  0, got: -1
```

Am I misunderstanding how `z3.LastIndexOf` is supposed to work or is there maybe a bug somewhere?

z3-solver version: 4.8.14.0 (installed via pip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug indeed. Please report it at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Thank you for your answer. [The issue is fixed now.](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/5856)